# Calculate sum of all values given in a range in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I sum of all numbers within a number range using PHP?

For example:

```
1-5 (1+2+3+4+5) = 15
```

Do I need to use `array_sum` or a variation of array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple options, here is 1.

```
$start=1;
$end=5;
$sum=0;
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
$sum+=$i;
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: in any real world application the speed advantage would be trivial

Answer (score 2):

Yeah use `array_sum()` and `range()`.

```
echo array_sum(range(1,5)); //"prints" 15
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/140867)</kbd>

Comment: certainly more elegant than my option, but a little slower according to my benchmarking ;-)

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1: Manually using loop**

```
<?php
$startNum = 1;
$endNum = 5;
$sum = 0;
for($i = $startNum; $i <= $endNum; $i++){
  $sum = $sum + $i;
}
echo "Sum of given range is ".$sum;
?>
```

**Check code with result**
[image]

---

**Solution 2: Using built-in functions**

Function `range()` is used to take given range and function `array_sum()` used to calculate sum of given range/array.

```
<?php
    echo "Sum of given range is ".array_sum(range(1,5));
?>
```

**Check code with result**
[image]

Comment: see: [Warning: Undefined variable $sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Comment: @Luuk answer updated. Actually the main thing is the logic.